# How to unit test functions without any logic?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm pretty new to unt testing and trying to do it "right" in my current project. Most of the functions is pretty straightforward but I'm stuck with classes/functions that mostly call on other classes/functions and if I should test them.

Say for example I have a class with these two functions:

```
public MyObject LoadObject(string path)
{
    string[] lines = fileService.ReadAllLines(path);
    return myParser.Parse(lines);
}

public void SaveObject(MyObject, string path)
{
    string[] lines = myConverter.Convert(MyObject);
    fileService.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
}
```

I guess I could mock out myConverter, myParser and fileService and then check if Convert(), Parse(), ReadAllLines() and WriteAllLines() have been called but does that really give me anything?

Comment: You don't unit test functions, you test functionality. What do those classes do? By their names I assume they save and load objects. So you'd write a test that saves something, then loads it and checks that the loaded data is ok.

Comment: This was just an example but I don't feel it's that straightforward. Most of the work is of course done is myConverter/myParser and those are tested seperately (so no need to test them here). My point is when I mostly do calls for other objects to do things, what should I test or should I test it at all?  I can verify the calls is made (and with the right arguments) and wonder if that's what people usually do in these cases or if they just skip to test them at all (except for later in integration tests maybe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to test that 'the function does what you expect'.  And what you expect is not that certain other functions are called.  What you expect is that, given certain inputs, certain outputs occur.

Consider `LoadObject` (which should probably be called something like `ParseFile` instead).  It reads a file and parses it.  So you want to test is what happens if you give it a known file:  does it parse it as expected?

You should separately test that `Parse` knows how to parse a legitimate set of lines and that `ReadAllLines` correctly turns a file into lines.  You can very thoroughly exercise the edge cases for both of those pieces of functionality in their particular unit tests.  For the purpose of this class, however, you only need to test that the aggregation works correctly.

The question a unit test asks is this:  assuming that my dependencies are implemented correctly, will this particular unit of functionality behave correctly?  So, stub out a `fileService.ReadAllLines` that returns a static string or throws an exception or whatever other categories of behavior the real `ReadAllLines` exhibits.  Stub out a `myParser.Parse` that returns a static data structure or that compares the lines to an expected input.

This function is not profound.  It shouldn't take a lot of tests to exercise it fully.

Comment: Yeah the name was pretty bad (just made it up). But I like your answer and will try to do this in my code, thanks!